# Amlify react app throws Error: Missing getServerSnapshot, which is required for server-rendered content. Will revert to client rendering

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

While running `yarn build` I get the following error:

`Error: Missing getServerSnapshot, which is required for server-rendered content. Will revert to client rendering.`

This didn't happened to me locally but only on the remote deployment, then I realized that remotely they use the latest amlify and next.js versions:
[image]

After updating next.js locally I managed to reproduce it locally - but didn't manage to solve.

Answer (score 0):

There's a GitHub issue that tracks this error: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/1780. A fix for it has been implemented and will be part of the next package release.

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing that i got the same error but for using `<ToastContainer />` on my app.js file ,simply remove it or find something else better